# Return an error from a nested Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Let's say I have this piece of code:

```
let queries = [Student.findById(idStudent), Actv.findById(idActv)];
Promise.all(queries)
        .then(result => {

            let student = result[0];
            let actv = result[1];

            if(student == null)
                return Promise.reject('Student not found');
            if(actv == null)
                return Promise.reject('Actv not found');
            if(student.actvs.indexOf(actv._id) != -1 || actv.studentsInscritos.indexOf(student._id))
                return Promise.reject('Student already signed up');

            Actv.find({field: '1234'})
             .then(qr => {
                 if(qr == null)
                    return Promise.reject('No actv found');
                //Do something else
             })
             .catch(err2 => {
                 //Error 
             })

        })
        .catch(err => console.log({"error" : err}));
```

When I execute the second query, it will not return any results, and it will throw an Promise rejection. How can I make the outter promise catch this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple. You have to return it and not catch it in the inner promise.

That should work:

```
let queries = [Student.findById(idStudent), Actv.findById(idActv)];
Promise.all(queries)
    .then(result => {

        let student = result[0];
        let actv = result[1];

        if(student == null)
            return Promise.reject('Student not found');
        if(actv == null)
            return Promise.reject('Actv not found');
        if(student.actvs.indexOf(actv._id) != -1 || actv.studentsInscritos.indexOf(student._id))
            return Promise.reject('Student already signed up');

        return Actv.find({field: '1234'})
         .then(qr => {
             if(qr == null)
                return Promise.reject('No actv found');
            //Do something else
         })

    })
    .catch(err => console.log({"error" : err}));
```

Comment: Return 'err2' or return the whole promise?

Comment: I added some code. You simply return the whole promise.